# How to get pkill to output process information of killed process?

Tags: kill, pkill, pgrep

How to get `pkill` to output process information of killed process?

I don't see anything in `man pkill` that suggests this is possible. I know I can do a `pgrep` and process the list and then pipe that to `kill` but hoping this is in native `pkill`. I also don't see anything inside `man kill` that suggests this either.

Comment: What process information do you want? `pgrep -a progname` will give you something in the style of `ps`. If you're using a specific system, there may be better than `pgrep` or `ps`.

Comment: I just want to output some user information in a script that kills an existing SOCKS tunnel that may have failed due to a re-connect. So, PID and command name I think.

Comment: Looks like it does output in bash, but not fish shell. Maybe that is my issue.

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/pgrep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-e` option: `pkill -e program`.

`pkill --help`:

```
-e, --echo                display what is killed
```

`pkill -V`:

```
pkill from procps-ng 3.3.15
```

Comment: `pkill: unknown option -- e`

Comment: @mosvy I have added my `pkill` version, please keep your comment, I hope we get an answer from `pkill` developer.

Comment: Notice that there's no linux tag ;-)

Comment: Looking at the GitLab repository, `-e` has been added to `pkill` in procps 3.3 (2012). It's probably safe to assume that it's available to most Linux users. OTOH non-Linux systems (I could test it on FreeBSD, "illegal option") most likely won't have it.

Comment: Thanks for the version info! I just checked one system that is on `pkill (procps version 3.2.8)` which doesn't have it and then checked my local system (Arch) with `pkill from procps-ng 3.3.15` and there is no `-e` or `--echo` option in `man pkill` BUT ... IT WORKS!!! Yay! Marked as accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: I added a screenshot, if it is confusing please edit and remove, if it helps please keep it.

Comment: No one understands that it is not `-v` but `-e` and it is not mentioned on the `man` page.